# BUY and HOLD rating for a stock

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

The following is the rating for the Walmart stock. One is a **BUY** rating targeting $149.28 in the next 12 months. The other is **HOLD**.

Both S&P and Walmart are at it's all time high at this time, doesn't a market crash cause the Walmart to drop significantly like 10 - 20%? If that is the case, do these ratings matter? If someone has an investment in Walmart at this time, should he protect his investment with PUT options or he should sell them?

**BUY Rating**

[image]

**HOLD Rating**

[image]

Comment: Requests for specific investment information or buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" are off-topic. Sorry. You can see what is on- and off-topic [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please consider that this question is not specific to the stock, but trying to find answer for the strategy in the case when the **market is at the peak** and the **stock has a BUY or HOLD** rating.

Comment: A consistently growing company will be at a all time high, like, every other day. Does that mean you should never buy it?

Comment: What makes you think that analyst ratings are accurate?

Comment: @JBChouinard Companies like **Walmart** is a growing company while other retailers have failed. I'm also trying to understand what **HOLD** means if I look at the **WMT** stock for the first time. Should I buy or if I don't buy more.

Comment: @Bob Baerker I don't know which one to trust. When I look at the second chart, the **S&P** is going higher but **WMT** is not growing in the same pace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these analysts believed that the market truly was at a peak and was destined for a crash soon, why wouldn't *every* stock be marked as a sell? The market as a whole is just one factor that goes into these recommendations. The potential for future growth, relative strength in the sector, and other factors play a part as well.

These recommendations are also geared more towards *long-term* investors, not day traders looking to time the market.

For this specific case, in economic downturns (e.g. recessions), discount retailers like Wal-Mart would probably fare *better* than higher-end retailers in the same space like Whole Foods. So their recommendation may be that the stock will perform better in the long run than its peers. Yes it *might* have a downturn along with the rest of the market, but those are short-term events. Over 5, 10, 15 years their prediction may be that Wal-Mart at least survives and then thrives coming out of the other side, versus other retailers that might not survive a downturn.

> If someone has an investment in Walmart at this time, should he protect his investment with PUT options or he should sell them?

***IF*** you use these ratings as your barometer, then you should buy more. If you think there's a chance of a downturn, then sure, using put options would be a way to insure your investment. But insurance is not free - you have to pay a premium to obtain that insurance.  Plus you have to know *when* the downturn will hit to know what tenor to use for your options. 1 month? 6 months? a year?

Comment: Do analysts actually factor in recessions ? I would think that you just analyse the underlying company and go from there ?

Comment: @xyious Maybe not recessions specifically, but certainly the overall economic outlook is a factor in determining future growth.